# What is called for those who have not realized their Saguna or Nirguna bodies?

Tags: brahman, terminology, mukti

Whoever has awakened to the true nature of their being is called *Brahman* in Hindu.
What is the called for those, who have not awakened to the true Nature ?

Comment: one who is in bondage is said to be a baddhAtma

Comment: one in bondage who is devout in their search for truth and knowledge for the sake of liberation is said to be a Mumukshu

Comment: Samsari is the word you're looking for. But as @SudarshanaSuri mentioned, Mumukshu is someone who is not yet enlightened but is on the path.

Comment: It should be Saguna. I have edited it.

Comment: So the name for one who is awakened to the true nature of their being shares the same name as the highest social class? One can be born into that awakened state, but never achieve it otherwise? Or am I conflating concepts?

Comment: @JamieClinton Brahmin is social class, Brahman is the ultimate reality in Hinduism.

Comment: Those who have not been awakened are bound jivas.

Answer (score 6):

There can be many obvious terms for non-realized beings, as "**deluded**" or "**covered by ignorance**" or "**bound**".

> BG 5.15 - The Omnipresent neither accepts anybody's sin nor even virtue. Knowledge remains covered by **ignorance**. Thus the creatures become **deluded**.
>   BG 3.27 — All actions are enacted in *Prakruti* by [3] modes (*guna*-s). **Bound** by ego(false identity), the self(*Atma*) believes *"'I' am the doer"*.

But there is no official term as such. :-)
BTW, *Nirguna* viz. quality-less cannot have a body which is a quality. So it cannot be realized as such

Answer (score 6):

Many words are used. In general a realized person is known in the scriptures as Atma GyAni, Tattvavid, TattvagyAni, Mukto etc.

Opposites will be Baddha (bound), agyAni (ooposite of GyAni) etc.

Have a look at the following verse (from KulArnava Tantram 9.42):

> Jivah shivah shivo jivah sa jivah kevalah shivah |
>   PAsha**baddhah** smrito jivah pAsha**muktah** sadAshivah ||
>
> The Jiva is Shiva; Shiva is Jiva; The Jiva is the Advitya (one without a
>   second) Shiva only. When the Jiva is bound by the PAshas (bondage)
>   it's Jiva and released of the PAshas it's SadAshiva.

So, Baddhah is used in this verse as the opposite of Mukto (liberated).

The purport is we are Jiva only as long as we are bound by the PAshas and we are none other than the Brahman himself once we are released of the bondages.

Answer (score 4):

One who is in bondage is referred to as **baddhAtma**. One in bondage who is devout in their search of truth and knowledge for the sake of liberation is said to be a **Mumukshu**.

*Reference: Artha Panchakam* (Verse 3 and 5, you can read from [here](https://ramanujadasan.files.wordpress.com/2011/04/apanca.pdf))

> (3). **The Baddhas, or the bound, are those souls who are turned away from the Bhagavan (God)**: (1) by reason
>   of their illusorily identifying their selves (souls) with the bodies which they wear; constituted as these
>   bodies are of the five material elements - impermanent cause of joy and grief - corrupt, so that in the
>   absense of the indwindling spirit (soul), they are unfit for the sight or touch - and which breed the mental
>   aberrations, such as ignorence (ajnAna), misapprehension (anyathA-jnAna) and reversed apprehension
>   (viparitha-jnAna) and (2) by reason of their notion that pandering to the pleasures of the body (catered to
>   by the five fold thralls of objects, sound, touch sight, taste and smell) is the be-all and end-all of their
>   existence. To secure such pleasures of senses, they infringe all the salutary dictates comprised in the
>   system known as varna and Asrama, become slaves to worldlings, inflict cruelty on creatures, seize
>   others's wifes and wealth, and thus swell the ranks of the mundane.
>
> (5). **The Mumuksus, or the Would-be Free, are those souls in whom the longing desire for salvation** (i.e.
>   reaching Bhagavan) has arisen. These are the two classes, viz. the UpAsakas, or the Strivers, and the
>   Prapannas, or the Resigned. The former seek salvation by self-effort, and the latter leave the same to
>   Bhagavan's (God's) care. The former thinks of salvation as his concern, whereas the latter thinks of it as
>   His concern.

Comment: Can you add exact reference to verse from Artha Panchakam?

Comment: @Pandya The verses and their translation are given in the document I've linked above. Feel free to edit them into the answer (I'm getting font issues when I tried).

Comment: I think 3rd not 2nd for Baddhas, just added.

Comment: So you are also unable to copy the tamizh verses? @Pandya

Comment: will add later, somewhat busy.